# Dartino Fibers share an outer space?

Tags: dart

In Dartino project, we have fibers.
https://github.com/dartino/sdk/wiki/Coroutines-and-Fibers
 What does it mean that fibers share an outer space and can't share immutable memory ? What is an outer space?
From "Curry On, Rome July 19th 2016 : Kasper Lund - Dartino: a managed language on micro-controllers?" : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t4IUhsuhnXw  --- 13:53